# Why do humans like to break the second law of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, soft-question, entropy

Roughly speaking, Entropy is a measure of the disorder of a system. However as humans, we tend to do the complete opposite. For instance, in a home if a painting that is hanging on the wall is crooked, we would feel an instant urge to correct it. Now the house (or even hallway, whatever) has become less random (in the sense that more things are orthogonal, parallel to each other) and we have reduced entropy.

Obviously we are not actually reducing entropy, because by moving the painting we do work and our own body increases entropy also, but let us ignore this for the moment.

There are many examples of this, we love patterns and regularity everywhere. In art, architecture, music, design even farming, we try to reduce entropy.

So my question is, is this a coincidence? Or is there some reason for this? One reason might be that by reducing entropy we increase the potential of our surroundings to "do work", but this seems a bit far-fetched to me.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're asking a question about human psychology; and we all know there is no rhyme or reason to that :)

Comment: This might be the wrong place to ask this question. I think the subject of this question depends more on the answer than the question. It could be physics, psychology or evolution, among others.

Comment: While a big (virtually 100%) majority of physicists believe that the brain is ultimately governed by the standard model of particle physics, we simply have nothing near a workable description of cognitive/psychological processes in fundamental physical terms. At present (and possibly forever into the future) physics is simply the wrong level of description to deal with this question, even if it's possible in principle.

Comment: You have already made the one actual physical statement that could be made ("Obviously we are not actually reducing entropy..."). The entropy of a crooked picture is absolutely microscopically irrelevant compared to that produced in a split second of chemical reactions in your body, so it is really unlikely that there is any meaningful entropic explanation of home decoration. :)

Comment: Off-topic for here; might be on-topic at [cogsci.se], once it was worded better

Comment: You might like reading Christopher Alexander's book series, The Nature of Order, which explores in depth exactly this sort of Human desire. (If you're actually applying his ideas as an architect, skip vol 3.  If you like metaphysics, be sure to read vol 4.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about psychology.

Comment: When ever there is an endless source of free energy, Like the sun, The system does not necessarily remain in equilibrium, and this allows for complexity.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a common misunderstanding about entropy that many people, myself included, struggle to understand.

I often thought that biological systems like embryos forming a human being broke entropy laws and this was just conveniently overlooked.  I now understand that that this process produces entropy in the form of heat.

In the case of straightening the picture, energy is expended in the process of re-organizing.  Thus entropy is not violated.

I found a recent article about the [reproduction rates of bacteria works almost at the ideal limits of thermodynamics](http://www.nature.com/news/bacteria-replicate-close-to-the-physical-limit-of-efficiency-1.11446) and which might help you understand how to quantify a complex process like this.  The author took what I thought was a unique approach:

> The minimum amount of heat that would 'just pay' for this order can be
>   determined by working out how much ordering is needed to turn raw
>   ingredients — amino acids and so forth — into a cell. This in turn can
>   be estimated by considering the reverse process: the likelihood that
>   the second cell could fall apart spontaneously into its components.

However if you try to apply this to human psychology and generalize that humans have a tendency to organize, that is a different story.  And I would submit that I know many self-destructive people, addicts, etc. that tend towards disorder.

Edit:  I should add that your example of straightening a picture is not an example of increasing order.  That's completely subjective state related to the [human tendency to enjoy visual symmetry](http://www.livescience.com/4002-symmetry-nature-fundamental-fact-human-bias.html).

Comment: Thanks for the papers, most interesting especially the replication thermodynamics one.